# HTML sendo construido antes de retorno da api em Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http-request, angular-material

Quero receber dados da minha API e construir cards com eles dinamicamente, para isso estou usando o 'binding' do Angular, porem meu HTML está sendo construído antes da resposta estar concluída, com isso ela é vista como undefined. Já tentei usar promises, mas sem sucesso, também tentei usar ngIf para que só gerasse os cards quando minha variável tivesse valor, outra vez sem sucesso.

**Service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IDisciplina } from 'src/app/shared/models/IDisciplina';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DisciplinaService {

  private UrlBase = 'http://localhost:5000/api/disciplina';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getDisciplinaById(Id: number): Observable<IDisciplina[]>  {
    return this.http.get<IDisciplina[]>(`${this.UrlBase}/${Id}`);
  }

  getDisciplinaByTurma(TurmaId: number): Observable<IDisciplina[]>  {
    return this.http.get<IDisciplina[]>(`${this.UrlBase}/getByTurma/${TurmaId}`);
  }

}
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DisciplinaService } from 'src/app/core/services/Disciplina/Disciplina.service';
import { IDisciplina } from 'src/app/shared/models/IDisciplina';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-Home',
  templateUrl: './Home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./Home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  DisciplinaPorTurma: IDisciplina[];

  constructor(private disciplinaService: DisciplinaService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ReceberDisciplinas();
    console.log(this.DisciplinaPorTurma);
  }

  ReceberDisciplinas() {
    this.disciplinaService.getDisciplinaByTurma(2).subscribe(
      (Disciplina: IDisciplina[]) => this.DisciplinaPorTurma = Disciplina,
      error => console.log('Falha na chamada. Erro: ' + error),
      () => console.log('Chamada a API finalizada!'));
  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<app-toolbar Titulo="UnipClassroom" LadoDireito="Henrique de Castro"></app-toolbar>
<div *ngIf="DisciplinaPorTurma">
  <app-spinner></app-spinner>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!DisciplinaPorTurma">
  <div class="container" *ngFor="let Disciplina of DisciplinaPorTurma">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <mat-card class="tamanho-card margin-card mb-4">
          <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title>{{Disciplina.Nome}}</mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-subtitle>{{Disciplina.CursoId}}</mat-card-subtitle>
          </mat-card-header>
        </mat-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ao invés de dar um **subscribe** no serviço em `HomeComponent.ts`, atribui a variável **DisciplinaPorTurma:** como sendo do tipo **`Observable<IDisciplina[]>`** e no loop do `Html` deixa com um **pipe async** assim **`*ngFor="let Disciplina of DisciplinaPorTurma | async"`**

Comment: Eu obtive dois erros ao fazer isso.
Primeiro no subscribe:
"Type 'IDisciplina[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<IDisciplina[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 5 more.ts(2740)"

A segunda foi com o pipe:
" InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você estava na direção certa. O detalhe que o nosso amigo disse de usar o pipe [async](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) é válido. A primeiro momento é um pouco confuso mesmo, mas vamos lá. Primeiramente altere o tipo do seu atributo para um **observable**

```
DisciplinaPorTurma$: Observable<IDisciplina[]>;
```

Após isso altere o seu método de consulta para:

```
ReceberDisciplinas() {
   this.DisciplinaPorTurma$ = this.disciplinaService.getDisciplinaByTurma(2);
}
```

Inclusive essa abordagem é uma boa prática para evitar possíveis vazamentos de memória (***memory leak***).
Feita essas alterações no seu arquivo ts, agora é só adicionar o pipe async no seu template.

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let Disciplina of DisciplinaPorTurma$ | async">
   <!-- Conteúdo aqui -->
</div>
```

Para facilitar o entendimento, montei um exemplo no [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-delay-loading)